# Change default null value in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, null, json.net, default

Is there some way to set what the default representation for null values should be in [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)?
More specifically null values inside an array.

Given the class

```
public class Test
{
    public object[] data = new object[3] { 1, null, "a" };
}
```

Then doing this

```
Test t = new Test();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);
```

Gives

```
{"data":[1,null,"a"]}
```

Is it possible to make it look like this?

```
{"data":[1,,"a"]}
```

Without using string.Replace.

Comment: No, because `{"data":[1,,"a"]}` is not a valid json.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The result is invalid JSON. If you were the author of a library that produces JSON, would you include an option that makes your library not work correctly on purpose?

Comment: That's not valid JSON - why would you want it to look that way?

Comment: @Jon I See. So wouldn't `{"data":[1,0,"a"]}` be valid Json?

Comment: @Flunx: It would. But instead of asking a human, hit `JSON.parse` on your browser console and get a guaranteed correct answer directly.

Comment: @Jon Ok thanks for the tip. So is it possible to replace null with 0?

Comment: Change class to public object[] data = new object[3] { 1, 0, "a" };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to implement a custom JsonConverter.
As others mentioned this will not produce valid/standard Json.

```
public class ObjectCollectionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType ==  typeof(object[]);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object[] collection = (object[])value;
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                writer.WriteRawValue(""); // This procudes "nothing"
            }
            else
            {
                writer.WriteValue(item);
            }
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
Test t = new Test();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t, new ObjectCollectionConverter());
```