# How can i ignore errors in json deserialization using [FromBody]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I use asp net core 3.0 and I have problem:

Model:

```
public class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Method in controller

```
[HttpPost("api/somePost")]
public Task Test([FromBody] Location location)
{
    // Do somethimg
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Startup:

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.Error = (sender, args) =>
            {
                args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
            };
        });
```

I send json with Postman

[image: postman request]

and get null in location parameter in controller method!

[image: error handler]

and

[image: controller method]

How can ignore error of type converting and get default value (0) in "Longitude" property?

Comment: If the `location` is `null` in the `HttpPost` there probably is something wrong with your JSON. How do you post it? Do you use the correct accolades (`{}`)? You can't expect a `string` to be serialized to a `double`, see `Longitude`.

Comment: Can you try calling your web api using postman and then update the question ?  Add what was your postman request and what error you received.

Comment: Doesn't the json need to be enclosed with `{}`?

Comment: Is location not null when all data is sensible?

Comment: The OP does not have a problem with this code or with the request, he just wants to handle the modelstate validation in a way that if there's a deserialization error it will be handled with default value instead.

Comment: To ignore or handle problems with the type of values, you will need to use custom converters, at least if you're using json.net for the deserialization.

Comment: updated with screens!

Comment: Please [no screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - post everything as text in the question. Otherwise the QnA will have limited value in the future when the screenshots gets deleted from wherever they're hosted.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349414/how-to-use-a-default-value-for-json-net-for-properties-with-invalid-values) would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a custom converter (as also mentioned in the comments).

```
public class YourCustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(double));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<double>(reader);
        }
        catch
        {
            return 0d;
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

Now you just decorate the properties you want this to be valid for with `JsonConverter`. For your example it would look like this:

```
public class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(YourCustomConverter))]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(YourCustomConverter))]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if you send in invalid data, the deserializer will throw an exception, which is catched by the custom converter that returns `0` instead (or whatever value you want it to be).

**UPDATE:**

Disclaimer: This is untested!

You could probably make a generic converter to handle all cases:

```
public class YourCustomConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

You could still use this as an attribute `[JsonConverter(typeof(YourCustomConverter<double>)]`.

There's also an option to use a custom converter for all JSON serialization/deserialization using this code:

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    // Configure a custom converter
    options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new SomeOtherCustomJsonConverter());
});
```

However, this can't really be made generic so you would have to write your own handling of all your possible types.

Comment: Thank you, it is work, but i need more unified solution, witch will work with all value types and without attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This [`JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=netcore-3.0) worked for me:

```
public class DoubleJsonConverter : JsonConverter<double>
{
    public override double Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        try
        {
            return reader.GetDouble();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, double value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        try
        {
            writer.WriteNumberValue((decimal)value);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            writer.WriteNumberValue(0.0);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
```

And

```
public class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DoubleJsonConverter))]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DoubleJsonConverter))]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution is a combination of [GTHvidstens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58372125/10883465) and [OPs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58376018/10883465).

Using the generic `JsonConverter<T>` is correct but you should not use `Convert.ChangeType` and `Activator.CreateInstance`, that part was better in GTHvidstens answer.

Below is the final version which should be faster (and arguably just more correct) than OPs version by using `default(T)` and `serialize.Deserialize`, while also taking advantage of the generic `JsonConverter<T>` used in OPs answer.

```
public class ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override T ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, T existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

What you do with this converter doesn't matter. One possible solution which will work is the one OP posted already - I don't see any issues with this approach.

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<bool>());
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<int>());
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<long>());
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<float>());
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<double>());
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<decimal>());
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<DateTime>());
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank everybody for help, the solution for me was:

```
public class ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override T ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, T existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(reader.Value, typeof(T));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And adding it in startup:

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<bool>());
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<int>());
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<long>());
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<float>());
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<double>());
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<decimal>());
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter<DateTime>());
        });
```

Comment: You should not use `Convert.ChangeType` and `Activator.CreateInstance` for this. [GTHvidstens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58372125/10883465) shows a converter which does the same thing but is simply _better_. Instead of `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` you should use `default(T)`. Instead of `Convert.ChangeType` you should just deserialize the value into the correct type with `serializer.Deserialize<T>`. Not only is it more correct, I assume it's also going to be faster. Take the converter from their answer and rename it to `ErrorIgnoringJsonConverter`. Your code in startup can stay.

Comment: I just noticed that they didn't use the generic version. The actual solution is a combination of your and their converter. I'll add an answer.

Comment: I have added [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58376362/10883465). As I said, both your and GTHvidstens answer had both good and bad features. I combined the good ones while keeping the interface the same so you can use it just like you did until now. Hope it helps :)